# how to use lookup('file') in ansible when the file might not exist?

Tags: ansible

I want to lookup the contents of a file on the ansible control node --

example:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    somevar: "{{ lookup('file', playbook_dir + '/some/path' + inventory_hostname) }}"
```

if the file does not exist I'd like the variable to be undefined or set to a default value.  The lookup module throws an error however if the file doesn't exist.  What's the right way to handle this error so that I can branch on the existence of somevar within my code?

Comment: I also tried via the set_fact module with ignore_errors: True ... 

TASK: [Lookup saved ssh hostkey for this host] ******************************** 
fatal: [nmf-spare-7800-3] => could not locate file in lookup:

Answer (score 6):

It seems that since this original post and now, this functionality has been added to the lookup plugin.

For me it works, I'm on version 2.8.5:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins
*New in version 2.6.*
*You can now control how errors behave in all lookup plugins by setting `errors` to `ignore`, ...*

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    somevar: "{{ lookup('file', playbook_dir + '/some/path' + inventory_hostname, errors='ignore') }}"
```

Comment: This does not work for `lookup('vars',...)`, there you only have a [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using local_action rather than lookup ...

```
- name: "Lookup saved ssh hostkey for this host"
  local_action: shell cat {{playbook_dir}}/path/to/{{inventory_hostname}}.pubkey
  ignore_errors: True
```

Comment: `ignore_errors` errors though will still throw an error. The playbook however will continue. If you dislike this, you could instead use `failed_when: false`, then it will silently skip all errors from the action.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically better better not to silently handle errors. You can use `ansible.builtin.stat` to check if the file exists and then `path_to_file_stat.stat.exists` in any conditional checks.

```yaml
- name: Check if /path/to/file exists
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: /path/to/file
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: path_to_file_stat

- name: Show file contents
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', '/path/to/file') }}"
  when: path_to_file_stat.stat.exists
```